# Late 90s-2000s scary movie that had a trailer with toes curling under a door

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I am trying to remember a movie from the late 90s or 2000s that had a trailer that involved toes sticking out from under a closet or bedroom door.

The toes curled up.

My family remembers this scene as well, as it was a trailer at the beginning of a VHS or DVD we would watch on road trips.

However, some of us remember different details that are potentially false:

- Curly shoe points instead of curling toes — like elf shoes, almost. (We think this may be misremembering a shot from *The Wizard of Oz* and conflating it with the toes, though.)
- In addition to the toes scene, it had a person walking/crawling on the ceiling like a spider, potentially with their head twisting 180 degrees.
- Potentially a clown movie?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What detail males you think it was a clown movie?  Was the crawling person naked?  A baby?

Comment: @DavidW, thanks for your reply! just a vague feeling, no actual concrete detail

Comment: *Killer Klowns from Outer Space* feels like it could have that kind of shot, although I think the shot I'm thinking of had a tongue rolling out between prison bars.

Comment: Welcome to [Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](/tour)! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as what movies you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our [guide on asking identification questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/7957).

Comment: + same question on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/1blf9ea/tomtmovie2000s_trying_to_remember_the_name_of_a/)

Comment: "*it had a person walking/crawling on the ceiling like a spider*" Do you remember if this scene involved firearms?